# Android Library 'commons-lang3-3.1' Importing Error

Tags: android

Hi I am having problem at importing 'commons-lang3-3.1' in Android Studio. I am facing problem with given details message. The error message is given below. And it may help you to solve the problem that I have pasted the **commons-lang3-3.1.zip** file directly in the **libs** folder. So do you think that for the zip format I am getting error message? Thank you.

> Error:(25, 0) Project with path ':libs:commons-lang3-3.1' could not be found in project ':app'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add to build.gradle file and rebuild project:

```
dependencies {
    compile  'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1'
}
```

Do not add zip to libs folder.

Comment: So you mean I will unzip the library at first and the put those files into the 'libs' folder? Or you said that no need to copy-paste? Forgive if I had done anything wrong

Comment: In this case no need for unzipping and copying files, Gradle will download library from central repository. Sometimes you need to put jar (not zip) to libs folder, if library is not present in central repository - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library

Comment: Thank you boss... :-) I am done. I have successfully imported the library.

Comment: Ah... Sorry brother. To vote you up I need 15 reputation which is unavailable to me. This is a new account to Stackoverflow. Otherwise I would vote undoubtly.

Comment: Ok brother, one more and that is - can I import any library like this way?

Comment: This way you can only import libraries presented in jCenter, read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31022373/how-does-publishing-android-libraries-that-can-be-imported-easily-by-other-peopl